# @react-native-async-storage/async-storage giving import errors in node_modules

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Have been using the library and was working fine and suddenly when restarted the application on metro bundler, it started giving the following error.

node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/src/index.ts: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module.

```
    // @ts-ignore AsyncStorage mock module
    declare module '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock' {
    export function useAsyncStorage(key: string): AsyncStorageHook;
    ^
    const AsyncStorageLib: AsyncStorageStatic;
    export default AsyncStorageLib;
    }
```

Have tried to delete node_modules and did npm install but the problem still persists.